# Nested categories without ul or other formatting

Tags: gwcode-categories, categories, nesting, child-categories

We have a 3 level category structure set up for a site. I would like to output these categories as JSON, while keeping the structure intact. As far as I can see, EE's native categories only allow outputting category hierarchy as ul or ol. I also tried Child categories & GWcode categories plugins, but at maximum I was able to output the two top levels only. Anybody have any idea how to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'll add this as a reference here, though I would avoid using it in a real life situation unless you are sure of what you are doing.

In stead of the many alternative ways to approach this, like using stash, embeds, a query or writing a plugin, I decided to tinker a little bit more with GWcode categories as it got me originally pretty close and seemed to have quite a few useful variables available.

While the solution could probably be easily modified to any arbitrary category structure depths, I highly recommend you do not use this solution in production. It is a messy hack (EE & JSON tend to get messy, but not this messy) and especially the last if-else structure feels a bit off, though it seemed to do what I needed it to:

```
 [{"categories":[
    {exp:gwcode_categories group_id="1" style="linear"}
        {if depth1_start || depth2_start || depth3_start}
        {if:else}
        ,
        {/if}

        {
            "id": {cat_id},
            "depth":{depth}

        {if has_children}
            , "childcategories":[
        {if:else}
            }
        {/if}
        {if group_end}
            ]} 
        {if:else}
            {if depth1_end && depth2_end && depth3_end}
                    ]}]},
            {if:elseif depth1_end && depth2_end}
                        ]},
            {if:elseif depth3_end}
                ]},
            {/if}
        {/if}
    {/exp:gwcode_categories}
]},{"performance": "{elapsed_time} seconds / {total_queries} queries"}]
```

An example of the JSON output can be found here: http://jsonlint.com/?json=https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/381221/jsoncategories.txt